# Flow Player Not Working For in Asp.Net C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, flowplayer

I am working in asp.net c# project, in that i have to play videos from folder path.

iam trying below code, the video path binding in datalist is correct, but when i press play button its always spinning, no videos display

```
<asp:DataList ID="DLVideos" RepeatColumns="2" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <a class="player" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block" href='<%# Eval("Column1","../Uploads/App_Videos/{0}") %>'></a>
    <br class="clear"/>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

<script src="../FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../FlowPlayer/flowplayer.embed-3.2.11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../FlowPlayer/flowplayer.embed-3.2.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $f("player", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf"); 
flowplayer("a.player", "../FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", 
{
plugins: {
  pseudo: { url: "../FlowPlayer/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.12.swf" }
         },
  clip: { provider: 'pseudo', autoPlay: false},
       });
 </script>
```

[image]

```
<a href="http://stream.flowplayer.org/flowplayer-700.flv"    class="player"
style="display:block;width:425px;height:300px;margin:10px auto"
id="player">
</a>
```

my question is : 
does flow player not support other video formats?(i have used .3gp format)

For Referance : http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/javascript/embed.html

pls help to play video in asp.net c#, any othe code welcome.

Comment: Does it have to be flash? Its dying you know... Try some HTML5 video